# date picker template not showing

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, infragistics, ignite-ui

Hi I am using `igniteui` library, in which I am trying to show custom filter on each columns. All columns are working fine except column of `dataType: 'date'`. I am trying to show my input box instead of date picker box, but it's template inside  is not showing. I tried almost all things, but not able to get the solution. Can anybody help what I am doing wrong. I am using version `12.3.3` of `igniteui-angular`

```
<ng-template #dateFilterTemplate igxFilterCellTemplate let-column="column">
        <div class="filter-cell">
            <igx-date-picker [value]="getFilterValue(column)" (onSelection)="onDateSelected($event, column)">
                <ng-template igxDatePickerTemplate let-openDialog="openDialog" let-displayData="displayData">
                    <igx-input-group type="box" #inputGr [displayDensity]="config.displayDensity">
                        <igx-prefix>
                            <igx-icon>search</igx-icon>
                        </igx-prefix>
                        <input
                            #input
                            igxInput
                            (click)="openDatePicker(openDialog)"
                            placeholder="Filter..."
                            autocomplete="off"
                            [value]="displayData | date"
                            [readonly]="true"
                        />
                        <igx-suffix *ngIf="input.value" (click)="clearInput(column)" tabindex="0">
                            <igx-icon>clear</igx-icon>
                        </igx-suffix>
                    </igx-input-group>
                </ng-template>
            </igx-date-picker>
        </div>
</ng-template>
```

Comment: Your sample code uses an older approach that replaced the entire `igxDatePickerTemplate` which was problematic for the internal picker handling is no longer supported. The up-to-date versions (12.0.0 and onwards) have updated templates that accept projected prefixes, suffixes and so on, much like the input group does, see https://www.infragistics.com/products/ignite-ui-angular/angular/components/date-picker#projecting-components

The sample from @Zdravko Kolev is using this approach to reproduce pretty much what the code above looks like and should be the way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

I tried to reproduce the problem with Ignite UI for Angular version 13 and everything is working well. Could you please make the necessary changes in order to reproduce with the following live-editing example:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-suknqo?file=src/app/grid/grid-filtering-template-sample/grid-filtering-template-sample.component.html